# How to index position in list of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a loop to process images that I have stored in a list of nd arrays.When I write the output on disk for an image,I want to get the index  of the corresponding array from list to have a unique name for that image.Here is what i am trying to do:

```
orb = cv2.ORB()
for i in feat_list:
        x=cv2.imread(i)
        kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(x,None)
        y = cv2.drawKeypoints(x,kp1)
        cv2.imwrite('D:\\diabetic\\feature\\output_orb\\featuredetect_%s.jpg'%feat_list.index(i),y)
        print("Processing done for "),str(i)
print("All pocessing done")
```

This gives me an error saying truth value of array is ambiguous.

Comment: try this: `print("Processing done for ", str(i))`

Comment: @mihir-deshpande If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is enumerate your list so you have an index and a value (image) available:

```
orb = cv2.ORB()
for index, image in enumerate(feat_list):
        x=cv2.imread(image)
        kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(x,None)
        y = cv2.drawKeypoints(x,kp1)
        cv2.imwrite('D:\\diabetic\\feature\\output_orb\\featuredetect_{0}.jpg'.format(index),y)
        print("Processing done for {0}".format(index))
print("All pocessing done")
```

Note here that I am using string Format which is more pythonic than using the C style string formatting.